# one aucmd of many to set filetype not working

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I have this group of `aucmd!`s:

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.dasc   set ft=c
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.fun    set ft=sml
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.hsc    set ft=haskell
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.hsc    set ft=haskell
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.json   set ft=javascript
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.lhs    set ft=haskell
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.ll     set ft=llvm
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.md     set ft=markdown
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl     set ft=prolog
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sig    set ft=sml
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sml    set ft=sml
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.td     set ft=tablegen
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.v      set ft=coq
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.x      set ft=text " alex
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.y      set ft=text " happy
```

Most of them work fine -- for example, by default when I edit a `.v` file vim chooses `ft=verilog`, but I override it in this block of `au!`s and I get `ft=coq` as expected. But for some reason the command for `*.y` never works -- I get `ft=yacc`. Any ideas what's special about that line, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this – it works as expected for me. Are you sure there isn't another autocommand or something else in your vimrc that's interfering? [Try following these steps](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need first to set the `verbose` option to 9 to show the log of every executed `autocmd`:

  ```
  :set verbose=9
  ```
- Now you can see the list for all related `autocmd` and where they are located by executing this command:

  ```
  :autocmd * *.y
  ```

---

The command below gives you more ability to search and parse the ouput generated by `autocmd` :

```
:new | redir =>output | silent exec "autocmd" | redir END | let @y = output | exec "put y" | g/\s\*\.y\s/
```

Comment: It turns out a plugin called `vim-syntax-extra` was overriding my ft command. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help ! :)